# Can I linearly combine the results of PCA with the variance of each feature?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I'm trying to reduce the dimension of a dataset from 8 features to 1 using the principal component analysis (PCA) algorithm. The reduced dataset needs to be in 1 dimension(D) so I can use it for matrix factorization and other algorithms.

However, after applying PCA, the reduced 1D dataset only keeps 45% of the variance so I'm loosing a lot of information. I tried to reduce the dimension keeping 95% of the variance but the resulting dataset has 3D.

I know the variance of each feature in the reduced dataset. Therefore, I was thinking of using the variances as weights and linearly combine them with the reduced values so I'd reduce the dataset further to 1D, for example:

```
value_1D = variance_f1*value_f1 + variance_f2*value_f2 + variance_f3*value_f3
```

Would it we correct to do it? Do you know any other alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It may be correct or reasonable in some specific investigatory context, but not generally. Components are uncorrelated, therefore constructing a linear combination of them is like adding apples to oranges. Sometimes we do add both together. Some psychometric scales, for example, are constructed disregarding any statistical correlation between the items being included, following purely nonstatistical reasons (such scale may be called battery of items). So yes, you may do it. The question is what for and how you are going to apply the result.

Comment: Thank you, I need the 1D dataset for matrix factorization to build a collaborative filtering recommender system. In this matrix, rows are users and columns are items. The value in each cell would be the 1D value for user-item. The features are: impressions, shares, clicks and more. All these features represent positive feedback. I tried to linearly combine the reduced dataset with the variances but the results don't look good as there are negative values so when I combine them it looks as a "negative feedback". However, If I use absolute numbers then the results are much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCA already finds the best lineair combination of features (the principal components) to explain the amount of variance. If you start combining the principal components, you will not explain more variance, since PCA already found the best lineair combinations. Essentially you are trying to perform PCA and then again PCA. You could try performing PCA twice, but you will find the exact same result.

What you could do is maybe the following. Let's say you have a dataset with 2 features, one feature is in m and the other in km. It is justified to change the units so all features share common units. This way you could inflate the amount of variance explained.

However, be careful. If you take this to the extreme case, you could say feature 1 is much more important than feature 2. You could arrive at the conclusion that feature 2 is useless, and multiply it by zero. Now feature 1 will explain all variance (100%). But this becomes meaningless, since you deleted feature 2. So don't start reweighting all your features to just increase the amount of variance explained ;) Note that you should do this before PCA.

Finally, you could ask yourself if it is nececary to keep a lot of variance for your goal. Maybe if your goal is classification, you could consider another method (find a lineair combination of features that tries to seperate the classes as much as possible for example). Otherwise it might be wise to take the 3D dataset and look for a method that can work with multidimensional datasets.

Comment: Thank you @tom, feature scaling has increased the amount of variance retained in feature 1. However, it's still not enough. I think I'll take your advice and look for a method that works well with multidimensional datasets.